# Identify Memory Leak from Heapdump - Cannot View Allocations from Heapdump in JProfiler

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jprofiler

I have been trying to identify the cause of a Memory Leak in my production application (It is throwing OutOfMemoryError and generating a Heapdump), I have identified some Objects which could be the cause (big objects which are referenced && not used), however, when I try to view where are these offending objects being allocated I am getting following message: *"This view is not available when viewing HPROF snapshots"* so my question is if Allocation View is only available for live profiling, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HPROF snapshots do not contain any information where objects were allocated. You have to use the JProfiler profiling agent and record allocation data before taking a heap snapshot in order to use this functionality.

Comment: Hello Ingo Kegel, thank you for the reply, does that mean that there is no way to identify the allocation just by analyzing a heap dump ? In that case could you recommend a way to track down memory leak just by having heap-dump available? (We cannot install agent on production environment because of the overhead and for legal issues). Thank you so much.

Comment: The allocations view is just one tool and you can track down memory leaks without it . I would start the "Biggest objects" view.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply Ingo Kegel, would it be a bad idea to load the JProfiler agent in production (because of overhead)? is it better to take a snapshot with jcmd command and then open it for analysis in JProfiler ? Thanks.

Comment: With the jpdump command line utility you can extract an HPROF snapshot (like with jcmd, only more convenient). However, you will not get the allocation information that you are looking for. Using the profiling agent in production is possible if you need this information to solve the problem.